# Xorg crashes when connecting dummy driver

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg

I have a laptop Asus X551M + ubuntu 22.04 + XFCE All package versions are the latest.
There was a need to connect the tablet as a second monitor.
Having rummaged through the Internet, I found the article  [“Tablet as a second screen for Linux”](https://habr.com/ru/articles/169003/) In accordance with the article, I added a description of the video card, monitor and screen to my configs. Here is the full config of what is there:

```
#Native video card
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Videocard0"
     Driver "intel"
     VendorName "Intel Corporation"
     BoardName "Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display"
     VideoRam 64000
EndSection
#Dummy video card
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Videocard1"
  Driver "dummy"
  VideoRam 128000
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
     Identifier "Monitor0"
# Identifier "eDP1"
# Identifier "DP1"
# Identifier "HDMI1"
# Identifier "VGA1"
# Identifier "VIRTUAL1"
     Option "Enable" "true"
     DisplaySize 1366 768
     #Modeline "1366x768 59.99*+
     #Modelline "1280x720 59.74
     #Modeline "1024x768 60.00
     #Modeline "1024x576 60.00 59.90 59.82
     #Modeline "960x540 60.00 59.63 59.82
     #Modeline "800x600 60.32 56.25
     #Modeline "864x486 60.00 59.92 59.57
     #Modelline "640x480 59.94
     #Modeline "720x405 59.51 60.00 58.99
     #Modeline "680x384 60.00
     #Modeline "640x360 59.84 59.32 60.00
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor1"
  Option "Enable" "true"
#DisplaySize 1920 1080
# HorizSync 10.0 - 300.0
# VertRefresh 10.0 - 200.0
# Modeline "1920x1200@10" 26.28 1920 1952 2048 2080 1200 1229 1231 1261
# Modeline "1920x1080@10" 23.53 1920 1952 2040 2072 1080 1106 1108 1135
# Modeline "1680x1050@10" 08/20 1680 1712 1784 1816 1050 1075 1077 1103
EndSection
Section "Screen"
     Identifier "Screen0"
     Device "Videocard0"
     Monitor "Monitor0"
     DefaultDepth 24
# SubSection "Display"
#Virtual 1366 768
#EndSubSection
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen1"
  Device "Videocard1"
  Monitor "Monitor1"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
     Virtual 1920 1080 #tablet resolution
     Depth 24
     Modes "1920x1080"
     Modes "1366x768"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Next, I declared the ServerLayout section, because the XFCE-Display dummy monitor does not see

```
#We set a scheme of 2 screens: left main, right dummy (tablet)
Section "ServerLayout"
     Identifier "dummy_layout"
     Screen 0 "Screen0"
# Screen 1 "Screen1" rightof "Screen0"
     Option "Xinerama" "1"
     InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
     InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

Does the system start fine in this form? but if I uncomment the line
Screen 1 "Screen1" rightof "Screen0"
then Xorg starts - I see a switch to graphical mode, and the flood crashes with an error in the log

```
[404] (EE)
[404] (EE) Backtrace:
[405] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x5627441f0979]
[406] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7f8a81653520]
[407] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[407] (EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f8a80db8e68]
[408] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[408] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f8a80e4dc8e]
[408] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2CreateDrawable2+0x21f) [0x5627441a9f2f]
[409] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (ht_dump_contents+0x6cf) [0x7f8a811fb1cf]
[410] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[410] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (?+0x0) [0x7f8a811ed3d8]
[411] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[411] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so (?+0x0) [0x7f8a811f0023]
[411] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (glvndGetExports+0x11eb) [0x5627441aff4b]
[412] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (glvndGetExports+0x20a0) [0x5627441b0e00]
[412] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x365) [0x56274407a4c5]
[413] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3c4) [0x56274407e544]
[414] (EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x90) [0x7f8a8163ad90]
[415] (EE) 13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f8a8163ae40]
[415] (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x562744067605]
[415] (EE)
[415] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[415] (EE)
```

Help me to understand.
I cant attaching a log of a normal start and a log with an error i cant see that possibility in the forum interface